# Как узнать в Django из какого класса сформирована страница?

Tags: python, django

При использовании class base view - как узнать в шаблоне (для выставления опций на странице) из какого класса вызвана страница?
Например есть класс

```
class foo(request, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    def some_action(self):
        pass
```

Из которого получается страница. В шаблоне страницы хотелось бы сделать условие вида:

```
{% if view.className == foo %}
    <input type='checkbox' checked = 'checked' />
{% endif %}
```

В своём решении делаю дополнительную переменную, значение которой проверяю в самом шаблоне через точечную нотацию `view`, но хотелось бы понять - есть ли более "прямой" способ?

Answer (score 0):

**templatetags/view_resolver.py**

```
from django import template
from django.urls import resolve

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def view_name(context):
    request = context.get('request')
    if request is None:
        return None
    v, _, _ = resolve(request.path)
    return '{}.{}'.format(v.__module__, v.__name__)
```

**some_template.html**

```
{% load view_resolver %}

{% view_name as name %}

{% if name == foo %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```